# create a new file in the background

Tags: command-line, search

How do I search for all files that start with the system's origin and redirect the error output to a file named errorfile.txt for example and the output of the redirection command to the files.txt file. Run in the background and view the two created files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find to the rescue:

```
sudo find / -type f 2> /tmp/errorfile.txt 1> /tmp/files.txt &
```

This will find all files starting from `/` and redirect the output as you asked. The `&` sends the command to the background. I suggest `sudo` because else you'll get numerous `permission denied` errors. But sure you can leave that out as a first step.